# what libraries should be linked in lex & yacc (solaris) to include YY_BUFFER_STATE

Tags: solaris, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

what libraries should be linked in lex & yacc (solaris) to include YY_BUFFER_STATE. when i use
YY_BUFFER_STATE in lex and compile it .i get an error saying tat it is undeclared.but when i do it in unix i am getting the output so pls help me.

Answer (score 2):

There's no library required for YY_BUFFER_STATE -- its all built into the generated scanner by flex.  However, it IS flex specific, so you have to use flex and not the lex that comes with solaris.

Answer (score 1):

The lex library is historically `libl` so it would be linked with `-ll`. A classical link line might be `-ll -ly` for lex and yacc.

Sometimes you need `-lfl` to specify the `flex` library.

Since you are on Solaris you may have the real lex/yacc and you may have the free versions, which are rather different in many ways. I think `YY_BUFFER_STATE` is specific to the free implementation.